# Case Merge History

Tags: case, merge

In Spring 20, you can [merge Cases](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cases_case_merge_ga.htm)

In our sandbox, I've tried merging 2 cases. I noticed it creates a case commeent

```
Case xxxx has been merged with Case yyyy
```

This is fine, but in the case history I'm seeing different things.
In Lightning, the merging doesn't appear in the case history

In Classic, you get a case history entry of

```
Case xxxx has been merged with .
```

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere that

1. adds a case history entry in lightning
2. makes the case history entry in classic consistent with the case comment created